# django-allauth: Conditional email verification

Tags: django, django-allauth

My site using django-allauth allows both social and traditional logins. Given that users have already verified their email addrs when signing up for external social accounts, I don't see the need to make them go through that process again.

I'd like to be able to require email confirmation for standard accounts but not for social signups. The `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION` options don't seem to allow for this flexibility. Is there a way to require verification for standard accounts but not for social accounts? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following setting:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"
```

Comment: Oh! Excellent, hadn't noticed that distinction. Thanks much.